# material UI Menu not appearing right place when button align right or left

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

In the first image material-UI menu position is working fine
[image]
but when we change the button position align-right that time menu position is some pixel left not exactly right align menu.
[image]

the question is how to align exactly the right side menu position without any margin right side.

Code Link : [Code Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-platform-vld9k?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: The problem is likely in your markup.  The containing `div` will govern how the Material UI is loaded.  Can you share the html?

Comment: @kiner_shah code added

Comment: @AuthenticScience code added

Comment: Looks like it's working though the menu gets a bit obscured by the nav bar.  If you can't sort it out with `zIndex` then just add `marginTop: "10px"` to `Menu PaperProps style ` and it should drop it down enough to be visible.
`

Comment: not marginTop issue, look like a margin-right issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the style of the element MuiPaper-root (in your version of the styling):

```
element.style {
    opacity: 1;
    ....
    transform-origin: 168.188px 0px;
    right: 10px;
    /* left: 235px; */
}
```

Note in the above left is removed and add 10px to the right one.

Comment: it will affect all three buttons if we add element style.

Comment: Can't you override the specifc style on one of the elements?

Comment: no, because it's a common component. if we change one, all other three buttons are affected

Comment: If you cannot separate it or check by some value than what you are looking for cannot be done at all.